# Javascript array null check without iterating

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I have an array like:  [null,null,null,null] in javascript.  How can I know if the array has all values equal to null without iterating over it?

Comment: searching an array is O(n)

Comment: just checking if there is a JS trick or shortcut to identify null array.

Comment: Avoiding iteration is impossible. If you don't loop over the array yourself, whatever method you call will have to. Is that your goal, to avoid explicitly looping over it yourself? That's possible.

Comment: Yep that is my goal. To avoid manual iteration. Code look ugly if i do that.

Comment: Perhaps '.valueOf()'

Comment: Or even simpler you can do an entire iteration and check on one line.                for(x=0;x<array.length;x++) if(array[x] == null) counter++;  later you could put if(counter == array.length) then you know that the entire array is full of null.

Comment: @Brendan - Or better yet `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) if(array[i] !== null) allNull = false;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to check for all `null` values, you would have to iterate over it, or the function you call will have to in the background. However, if you want, you could use the native Array method `filter` to help you out.

```
var allNull = !arr.filter(Boolean).length;
```

This will work with any falsy value, like undefined, zero, NaN, or an empty string. A more precise form is

```
var allNull = !arr.filter(function(elem){ return elem !== null; }).length;
```

Which would check for *only* null.

Another possibility is using `.join`:

```
var allNull = !arr.join("").length;
```

This checks for `null`, `undefined`, or `""`

Answer (score 4):

There are various built–in methods to help, one is [*every*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.4.4.16) to test that every value isn't null. It will return *false* at the first null:

```
var noNulls = array.every(function(value){return value !== null});
```

Another is [*some*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.4.4.17), which will return *true* at the first null:

```
var hasNulls = array.some(function(value){return value === null});
```

Comment: `every` is indeed a helpful method. I didn't even remember it existed.